# Are there millions of cases of girls raped by Muslim men in Europe which resulted in only 222 convictions?

Tags: criminology, immigration, europe, muslims

Recently I saw a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLT9JOE64WQ) where the first minute of the video seems to show a British man talking in Parliament where he says that since 2005 there were millions of rapes of female children (he says "girls") in Europe by muslim men, and only 222 convictions:

> If we accept the views of our leader(?) police officer for child protection, of Robberins(?) MP, and of the recent Jay and Quilliam report,
>   we seem to be looking at millions of rapes of white and Sikh girls by Muslim men, only 222 of whom have been convicted since 2005.

What do the data say? Is there any truth to these allegations?

Comment: Please do not make us go elsewhere to find out what this is about. I have added an essential quote from the video, with question marks where I am unsure of the spelling. Maybe there are more.

Comment: That video refers to [a website](https://www.minds.com/Sargon_of_Akkad/blog/western-sharia-police-869654578125615104), mentioning 'sources' which I have not taken the time to follow up. Could be worth it for an answer.

Comment: I think even the most willfully ignorant of people would notice MILLIONS of rapes.  It would mean otherwise turning a blind eye to a significant portion or even the entirety of the female population being raped.  The claim is patently ludicrous simply on its scale alone.

Comment: Well, I asked about "Europe", but someone edited the question to be only about the UK. So maybe that's why it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 11):

There is no evidence for this.

The video supplies two sources: A Quilliam study and a police officer. Neither say that there are millions of rapes by Muslims, and the 222 convictions are not related to alleged rapes committed by Muslims.

**Only 222 convictions**

The given source is an unnamed Quilliam study. It is the study referenced [here](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/quilliam-grooming-gangs-report-asian-abuse-rotherham-rochdale-newcastle-a8101941.html), which isn't about rape of children in general, nor about Muslims or illegal immigrants.

> The organisation [...] said it found 222 of 264, or 84 per cent, of people convicted of specific grooming-gang crimes in the UK since 2005 were Asian.

There is [doubt](https://medium.com/@Reg_Left_Media/grooming-gangs-quilliam-the-myth-of-the-84-percent-cc834b57fcf3) about the Quilliam findings:

> Laced with contradictions, misrepresentations and blatant fabrications, the report also appears hastily thrown together, with paragraphs copied and pasted into multiple sections. Their statistics are pulled from incomplete research, and use a specific definition of ‘grooming gangs’ that is again different from the figures they cite from other studies. The report has been highly selective of not only the references it opts to use, but the specific sections of those sources it decides to include or omit.

**Rotherham and millions of victims**

The second source that is given in the video is a Rotherham police officer.

Rotherham is the place where a [child sexual abuse scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotherham_child_sexual_exploitation_scandal) took place.

The police officer [said](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-29639374):

> We don't know for sure. But I think it's tens of thousands of victims [a year] of an appalling crime," Mr Bailey said. [...]
>
> "[The] bigger picture is that 90% of child sexual abuse takes place in the home where crimes are being perpetuated upon victims by people they know already. It is really important that we get some context around this."

Using this as evidence of millions of rapes by Muslims makes no sense; the officer is talking about child sexual abuse in general, and that the perpetrators are overwhelmingly people the victim knew already.

**tl;dr** There is no evidence at all for millions of rapes by Muslims. The 222 convictions mentioned are related to "grooming-gang crimes", not rape of children in general, and thus do not show an inaction on the part of the UK in response to rape.